How to fix URL opening with www prefix in Microsoft Edge
I have a URL desktop shortcut controlled by group policy with a single label name web page address to a site hosted on Windows Server 2022  IIS.
The address in the desktop shortcut does not contain the www prefix, however Microsoft Edge opens with www in front of the address, and the address does not resolve to the web page.
The DNS server has DNS records for the domain name that include the IP address of the server for both the domain name and www addresses.
The link works in Firefox and Chrome web browsers.
Microsoft Edge throws a DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
link fails to resolve in Microsoft Edge
Does anyone have a fix for this?
Actual URL in the desktop shortcut:
http://tmc-vault/AutodeskTC/TMC_Vault

URL that launches in Microsoft Edge:
http://www.tmc-vault/AutodeskTC/TMC_Vault


What is the actual link in the shortcut?

@Massimo Yes, the actual link was in the desktop shortcut. Correct link stored in the short cut:    http://tmc-vault/AutodeskTC/TMC_Vault    URL that opens in Microsoft Edge:    http://www.tmc-vault/AutodeskTC/TMC_Vault

The URL should include a FQDN; I don't see a domain name there.

@Massimo your suggestion was the solution. I created a domain record in IIS for TMC-VAULT.local then added a DNS record for TMC-VAULT.local to point to our server IP address. Now, the desktop shortcut opens without the prepended www sub-domain in Microsoft Edge.
Thank you for your help.
